# SI DSL: Difference between handle() and channel() in flow definition for AMQP queues

Tags: spring-integration

I've reviewed the documentation I can find and haven't worked out an answer so was hoping to get some enlightenment here. Is there any difference between these two calls?

```
.handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey("my-queue"))
.channel(Amqp.channel(connectionFactory).queueName("my-queue"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all let's come back to the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-channels) any way:

> Prior to version 4.3, AMQP-backed channels only supported messages with Serializable payloads and headers. The entire message was converted (serialized) and sent to RabbitMQ. Now, you can set the extract-payload attribute (or setExtractPayload() when using Java configuration) to true. When this flag is true, the message payload is converted and the headers mapped, in a similar manner to when using channel adapters. This allows AMQP-backed channels to be used with non-serializable payloads (perhaps with another message converter such as the Jackson2JsonMessageConverter). The default mapped headers are discussed in Section 11.12, “AMQP Message Headers”. You can modify the mapping by providing custom mappers using the outbound-header-mapper and inbound-header-mapper attributes. You can now also specify a default-delivery-mode, used to set the delivery mode when there is no amqp_deliveryMode header. By default, Spring AMQP MessageProperties uses PERSISTENT delivery mode.

So, typically (by default) `Amqp.channel(connectionFactory)` sends the whole `Message<?>` to the target queue. Meanwhile the `Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate)` does exactly opposite - map the `payload` to the `body` and headers:

```
if (this.amqpTemplate instanceof RabbitTemplate) {
        MessageConverter converter = ((RabbitTemplate) this.amqpTemplate).getMessageConverter();
        org.springframework.amqp.core.Message amqpMessage = MappingUtils.mapMessage(requestMessage, converter,
                getHeaderMapper(), getDefaultDeliveryMode());
        addDelayProperty(requestMessage, amqpMessage);
        ((RabbitTemplate) this.amqpTemplate).send(exchangeName, routingKey, amqpMessage, correlationData);
}
```

The AMQP-backed channels are aimed for the `persistence` and should not be used in the logic which relies on the messages content.

Comment: In other words; use `.handle()` if you want to end a flow by sending a message to rabbit. Use `channel()` if you need to persist a message mid-flow (between components in the same application). You should __not__ use channels to distribute messages between applications (it's ok to use them when you have multiple application instances, but there's no guarantee the same instance will get the sent message unless each instance gets its own queue).

Comment: Thanks to you both for the explanation.

Comment: Will do. In my case, I'm trying to break up stages of a process so that multiple instances can divide up the work. Based on what you are saying and the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-channels), I believe I should be using channel adapters to achieve this.